# I am having an issue with my "top of the screen" button script

Tags: javascript

I created a database to display information to my user. I decided to put a "To the top of the page" button to help my users scroll to the very top of the page. It worked fine when I used `<script>` tags but I decided to clean it up (hoping to code like the pros) and create an external js folder, but it stopped working when I did so. I could no longer see the button when I scrolled down the page. I have very little experience with scripts, so any help is much appreciated.

```
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <script src="/js/top.js"></script>    
   
</head>
<body>
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Return to Top</button>
```

js external file - top.js

```
//Get the button
        var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

        // When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
        window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

        function scrollFunction() {
        if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
        mybutton.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            mybutton.style.display = "none";
            }
        }

        // When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
        function topFunction() {
        document.body.scrollTop = 0;
        document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        }
```

Comment: Seems to me like the old problem, where a script is executed before the document is loaded completely. You might go for that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/how-to-make-javascript-execute-after-page-load

Answer (score 2):

You include the `script` before `myButton` is in the DOM so your call to `document.getElementById("myBtn");` returns `undefined`. You should include your `<script>` tag at the end of the page (just before `</html>`, so all the of the DOM is loaded before you try to do any operations.

There are other methods to this as well for instance

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { 
// your code here
})
```

would only run your code after the DOM content is loaded.

Comment: I tried                                                                                                                             
 `</body>
<script src="/js/top.js"></script>
</html>`                                                                                                                               
 but it is still not working

Answer (score 1):

I kept playing with it and took the suggestions mentioned (thanks). It is working now. I moved the `<button>` and `<script>` tags before the `</body` tag.

```
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Return to Top</button>
<script src="js/top.js" defer></script>
```